# fgetcsv returns too many entries

Tags: php, unix, fgetcsv

I have the following code:

```
while (!feof($file)) {
        $arrayOfIdToBodyPart = fgetcsv($file,0, "\t");
            if (count($arrayOfIdToBodyPart)==2){
```

the problem is, the contents of the file look like this:

```
39      ankle
40      tibia
41      Vastus Intermedius
```

and so on

sometimes, the test in the if will show *three* entries, with the first being the number, the second being the name, and the third being just... emtpy.

This causes the if block to fail, and me to be sad. I know i can just make the if block test for >=2, but is there any way i can get it to just recognise the fact that  there are two items? I don't like that the fgetcsv is finding "mystery" characters at the end of the line.

Is this possibly a unix server running a windows-based file error? If so, and i'm running an ubuntu server without dos2unix, where  do i get it?

Comment: +1 for emotional reactions to problems in your code/data

Comment: Try doing a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) of the CSV file to see if the file's contents match your expectations; the actual contents might differ from your initial assumptions. It's necessary to do this with something like a hex editor instead of a text editor, since the latter won't always distinguish between bytes that PHP definitely does treat differently.

Comment: my guess is CR chars (\r) before the NL char (\n). Use `dos2unix filename` to clean them up. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have tabs at the end of a line:

```
value<tab>value<tab><newline>
```

If that's the case, dos2unix won't help you. You might have to do something like read each line into a variable, trim() the variable, and then use  str_getcsv() to split it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a tab at the end of those lines? They are invisible and often hard to spot... you might want to double check.

Also if you are working with csv files, while you are running windows locally and the server is unix, I found this line:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

saves a lot of headaches.